# Combining Lists of Possible Different Data Formats

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists that I would like to essentially inner join in Python based on Product (Product appears in both tables). One list is one-dimensional and the other is multi-dimensional. I think my issue with combining them may be the data formats.

```
list1 = ['Product A','Product B','Product C','Product D']
list2 = [('Product F','10'),('Product A','30'),('Product D','40')]

joined = [item1+item2[1:] for item1 in list1
                            for item2 in list2
                                if item1[0] == item2[0]]
print joined
```

Desired output:

`[('Product A', '30'),('Product D','40')]`

I'd also like to eventually combine elements of this tuple with a string to generate some html code:

```
for row in joined:
    html_table_body = ""
    html_table_body = html_table_body  + "<tr><td>Item:" + joined[1] + "</td></tr>"
print html_table_body
```

This yields the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
[item for item in list2 if item[0] in list1]
```

For the other part, you can use

```
html_table_body = ""
for row in joined:
    html_table_body += "<tr><td>Item:" + row[1] + "</td></tr>"
print html_table_body
```

Comment: @user2242044 Check edits. In future, ask that as a new question, StackOverflow format is one question per post.